# Magento can't open a file outside its base dir with fopen

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, file

For some reason to me unknown, Magento doesn't want to open file for writing with:

```
$fp = fopen("/Users/vlado/Desktop/f.txt", 'a+');
```

, apparently because it is outside of the Magento base directory. In other words, this works:

```
$fp = fopen("media/f.txt", "a+");
```

Both files `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/magento/media/f.txt` and `/Users/vlado/Desktop/f.txt` have 777 chmoded to them. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: It's most probably due to /Users/.... being outside of the server root so php can't write to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open file for writing with below code.

```
$fp = fopen("/Users/vlado/Desktop/f.txt", 'w);

$fp = fopen("media/f.txt", "w");
```

Comment: No I can't. This is exactly the point of my question. I can write to file inside Magento base folder (like media/) and I can't write to a file outside of it.